# Stationarity of Time Series

Tags: hypothesis-testing, stationarity

There are different test for staionarity testing of time series.

One of the methods is to detect the trend in the time series.

Dracup and others(1980) fitted a trend line to the time series and estimated the slope.

But I have not understood how they did the hypothesis testing. That is how to test if the slope is significant.

They talk about a "t" static and alfa value. But it did not become absolutely clear how they estimated the t static While the decision maker can decide the value of alfa such as 0.05 or 0.01, but how is the t static or the p value estimated from the data to make a decision.
Any help will be much apprecited